# Create a java file inside a package

Tags: java, eclipse, eclipse-plugin

Currently, my plugin creates a java file in my project(IProject).  But I want that java file within a specified Package.  How to do it.

```
IFile sampleFile = parentFolder.getFile("Sample.java");
        if(!sampleFile.exists())   FileInputStream fileStream = new FileInputStream("C:\Users\Uma\Desktop\treasureHunt\Application.java"); sampleFile.create(fileStream, false, null);
```

This is my current piece of code.
How can I create the sampleFile within a package. For example: in package com.mdh.se as com.mdh.se.Sample.java

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have a "package" (e.g. "com.mdh.se") then you'll have a corresponding subdirectory (for example, "c:\users\uma\desktop\treasurehunt\com\mdh\se").  Simply write your file there.

Answer (score 0):

I think, that the only thing you need to do is to create folders representing your package structure. So your path should look like C:\Users\Uma\Desktop\treasureHunt\com\mdh\se\Sample.java for your example.

Comment: Yes, you are right.  I will try this way.  But in eclipse, packages are represented in a different way right?  They look like special kind of folders!

Comment: I think, that the representation depends on the IDE itself, but the source code must be structured in this way, because it's standard java source files organization. But you may have to register the new source somehow to your IDE or make your IDE refresh the project.

Answer (score 0):

You can get a special file inside the package by calling

```
java.net.URL imgURL = ResourceManager.class.getResource( "ResourceManager.class" );
```

From these URL you can extract the directory, the file is placed.

A new file you can create with

```
new File(directory,filename);
```